# Proof by induction: every partial order on a finite set can be extended to a linear order

Tags: solution-verification, induction, order-theory

I want to prove that every partial order on a finite set $X$ can be extended to a linear order and I want to do it without assume the axiom of choice.

I try to do a proof by induction on the cardinality of the set $X$.

Base case:
If $|X|=0$ then $X=\emptyset$, then the unique partial order on $X$ is given by the void relation, that is also a linear order.
If $|X|=1$ then $X= \{ x \} $, then the unique partial order on $X$ is given by the relation $x \le x$, that is also a linear order.

Induction step:
Suppose that every partial order on a set with cardinality $n-1$ can be extended to a linear order. Let's consider a partial order on a set $X$ with cardinality $n$. How can I extend this partial order to a total order?

Comment: Assume and prove more: That they have a maximal element and a linear order extending the given order. In the induction step, remove a maximal element. Extend the partial order of the remaining set and make the removed element larger than the rest.

Comment: @user85667 in the induction step how can I prove that a set with cardinality $n$ has a maximal element?

Comment: Many ways. You could take out one element $y$. Then the remaining set has maximal element(s) $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. If there is at least one $x_i$ such that $y\not\geq x_i$ (note that this happens either when $y<x_i$ or when $y$ and $x_i$ are incomparable). Then $x_i$ is maximal of the original set. If for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ we have $y\geq x_i$, then $y$ is maximal of the original set.